# Need to verify if my SQL queries are correct

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

## Description of Tables

There are three tables involved in this question: `transactions`, `segments` and
`products`, which simulate a simplified retail data schema.  Here is a semantic
description of the tables:

1. `transactions`: contains detailed information about each product a customer
   has purchased.  A transaction consists of one or more products purchased by
   a customer indexed by a unique transaction id.

   - `trans_id`: the transaction id
   - `cust_id`: the customer id
   - `prod_id`: the product id
   - `item_qty`: the quantity of the product that is being purchased
   - `item_price`: the per unit price of the product (NOTE: the total revenue
     for a product is `item_qty * item_price`)
2. `products`: contains detailed attributes about each product.

   - `prod_id`: the product id (same meaning as in `transactions`)
   - `prod_name`: the product name
   - `brand`: the brand of the product
   - `category`: the category of the product
3. `segments`: contains a history of customer segmentation labeling for each
   customer.  Segments are computed periodically for all current customers and
   appended to the table after each computation.  The current (most up to date)
   active segment for each customer is specified by `active_flag = 'Y'` column.

   - `cust_id`: the customer id (same meaning as in `transactions`)
   - `seg_name`: the segment of this customer
   - `update_dt`: the date when this segment was updated
   - `active_flag`: whether or not this segment is the active segment for this customer

QUESTION: 
. Find the most popular category (by revenue) for each active segment.
   *Hint*: The current (most up to date) active segment is specified by `active_flag = 'Y'` column in the segments table.
   Here is the some sample output:

```
seg_name    category    revenue
INFREQUENT  Women       20264
```

MY ANSWER:

```
 SELECT s.seg_name, p.category, SUM(t.item_price) revenue
FROM segments s
JOIN transactions t
ON s.cust_id = t.cust_id
JOIN products p
ON p.prod_id = t.prod_id
WHERE s.active_flag = 'Y'
GROUP BY p.category
ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

[image: This is the output I am getting]

Is this the correct query? Thanks in advance

Comment: `(NOTE: the total revenue for a product is item_qty * item_price)`, you're just summing the price.  Also if you just want the most popular you could do `top(1)`

Comment: No. Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: @Ankvis . . . You have an instructor for this.

Comment: SELECT s.seg_name, p.category, (t.item_qty*t.item_price) as revenue 
FROM segments s, transactions t, products p
where t.cust_id=s.cust_id
and p.prod_id=t.prod_id
and s.active_flag='Y'
group by s.seg_name , it is still not correct but I have used item_qty * item_price as mentioned in the description.

Comment: just asking for help, if someone can fix it.

Comment: If it still does not work, then post sample data as text - **no images**, the expected results of that data, and what you are actually getting. Also explain the differences as best you can; which items are in the result, which items are missing from the result, which are in the result but incorrect.  That is what we need to help you.  We are willing to help, but you need to give us as much information as possible, not doling out as little as possible.